# Have JPA/Hibernate to replicate the "ON DELETE SET NULL" functionality

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been able to have JPA/Hibernate to replicate the `ON DELETE CASCADE` functionality successfully (seems like the default behaviour) but I'm now trying to replicate the `ON DELETE SET NULL` functionality and I'm facing problems.

These are my two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private List<Student> studentList;

    // ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable = true)
    private Teacher teacher;

    // ...
}
```

When I try to delete a teacher, the following error appears:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [delete from teacher where teacher_id=?]; constraint [null]
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 delete from teacher where teacher_id='1' was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it something achievable?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to set all the columns of that record to null ? or all the fields of the student entity

Comment: I want the `student`'s `teacher` column to become `null` after the `student`'s `teacher` is deleted from the system.

Comment: Not that you want to change your schema for JPA, but I'd be curious the effect of changing it to a ManyToMany with cascade deletion on the join table. It should delete the association and leave the student.

Comment: Here's a feature request on the Hibernate Jira for supporting `@OnDelete(onDeleteAction=SET_NULL)`: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4410

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible at the moment with jpa/hibernate.

[On delete set null in hibernate in @OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243400/on-delete-set-null-in-hibernate)

JBs solution seems clean though:

```
for (Department child : parent.getChildren()) {
    child.setParentDepartment(null);
}
session.delete(parent);
```

You should also be able to put it in a PreRemove:

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
    for (Student s : studentList) {
        s.setTeacher(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both the solutions work perfectly. I personally prefer the second one :)

Comment: The `@PreRemove` solution is not portable. See JPA spec section 3.5. *In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not [...] modify relationships within the
same persistence context.*

Comment: This works, but when I delete 'Student' from 'Teacher' and I want to add the same 'Student' to different 'Teacher' - it simply doesn't work - 'Student' has null 'Teacher' in DB.

Answer (score 7):

What about defining

```
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_student_teacher",
            foreignKeyDefinition = " /*FOREIGN KEY in sql that sets ON DELETE SET NULL*/")
```

?

Comment: This is only used to specify foreign key constraints in the associated database, when schema generation is in effect.

Comment: This is not database neutral, other than that it is the best approach as it is clear, logical and fast.

Comment: Note that the `@ForeignKey` annotation cannot be used directly on the field or property, it must used within a another annotation, e.g. `@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(...))`

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best solution is a user SQL statement for setting on delete action as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

when user deletes a row by other cascading delete where you use a table reference to this deleted row, you could not use hibernate solution and return SQL exception.