# JPA Cascade remove relation without removing children, and also updating children

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, cascade, bidirectional

I'm using Spring Data JPA, I have a **Category** object as following:

```
@Entity(name="category")
public class Category {

  @ManyToOne
  private Category supercategory;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="supercategory")
  private List<Category> subcategories;

  // ...
}
```

Now, whenever I remove any *supercategory* the *subcategories* "supercategory_id" is **not** updated to **NULL** in MySQL.

I don't want to remove the subcategories, just to remove the relation, which is by **nullifying** the "supercategory_id" column in the DB.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in the question. You need to nullify the supercategory field of the sub categories, since that's the field which is mapped to the supercategory_id column in the database.

Comment: Have a look at this for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944137/have-jpa-hibernate-to-replicate-the-on-delete-set-null-functionality